# Find and copy the latest file

Tags: vb.net, vbscript, xcopy

Our program is going to save PDFs to a network folder.  I will then be copying the PDFs to a web server.  There becomes a problem when a user saves/archives the same report more than once.

Example:

- DAGH4 (002).PDF - Date Modified = 3/16/2016 10:10 AM
- DAGH4 (001).PDF - Date Modified = 3/16/2016 9:00 AM
- DAGH4.PDF - Date Modified = 3/16/2016 8:00 AM
- DANYL (001).PDF - Date Modified = 3/16/2016 10:50 AM
- DANYL.PDF - Date Modified = 3/16/2016 9:50 AM

Is there a way I could copy the latest version?  I only want DAGH4 (002).PDF and DANYL (001).PDF to be copied.  Or is there a way to rename and save the latest version?

**Another thought**

Using this code I check if the file exists and allow the user to click an thumbnail to open the associated PDF.

```
Dim pdf_path = Server.MapPath(String.Format("../Reports/{0}.pdf",     
SerialNumber))
lblSerial.Visible = System.IO.File.Exists(pdf_path)
HyperLinkSerial.Visible = System.IO.File.Exists(pdf_path)
HyperLinkSerial.Text = "Inspection"
HyperLinkSerial.NavigateUrl = "../Reports/" & SerialNumber & ".PDF"
```

However, I need to only find and show the DAGH4 (002).PDF with the modified date 3/16/2016 10:10 AM

Is that possible using VB .NET?

Comment: why so many tags?  are you doing this in PowerShell, a batch file, or vbscript?  Pick one please...

Comment: are the serialnumbers always the last part before  the .pdf extension and formatted as (001)?

Comment: Yes.  Exactly as shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the latest copy of each file, you could use LINQ to group by serial number, sort by modification date, and select the first item for each group.  Note that this assumes that your "SerialNumber" is just letters and numbers (what the regex matches):

```vb
Dim latest As IEnumerable(Of String) =
    From f In New DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath("../Reports")).EnumerateFiles("*.PDF")
    Let serialNumber = Regex.Match(f.Name, "^\w+").Value
    Order By serialNumber Ascending, f.LastWriteTime Descending
    Group By serialNumber Into Group
    Select Group.First().f.FullName
```

`latest` will have the full path/name for the latest (based on modification date) file for each serial number.

Comment: I have not used From.  How should it be declared?

Comment: @crystalnoob Hmm, what version of Visual Studio and/or .NET are you using?  LINQ was added in VS2008 / .NET 3.5.  There may be some references and/or imports you need to add.

Comment: @crystalnoob Too bad, sorry.  At least it's not VB6! :-)

Comment: Just converted to 2008 without error.  Showing a problem with Order By.  Says not declared.  The whole line "Order By SerialNumber Ascending, f.LastWriteTime Descending" says a comma or ) is expected.

Comment: @crystalnoob I would have expected issues with other parts of the query.  `DirectoryInfo.EnumerateFiles` may be a .NET 4 thing, so you could use `GetFiles` instead.  Also, may need `Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions` for the `Regex` class.  I think `Order By` would be supported, so I'm hoping there is actually an error on a prior line causing that error.  Maybe add `Imports System.Linq`, and I suppose check that `System.Core.dll` is referenced.